# How to read a numeric expression from user in R studio

Tags: r, user-input

I want to read a numeric expression (ex:- 9/3) from the user during runtime and print the answer(3). I used readline() but since it reads the line as a string, when as.numeric() function is applied the output is NaN. How do I convert the expression to get a numeric value?

This is the code I used.

expression = readline(prompt = "Enter the expression : ");

exp = as.numeric(expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid the danger mentionned by @BenBolker you can use the **Ryacas** package:

```r
library(Ryacas)
expression <- readline(prompt = "Enter the expression : ")
yac_str(expression)
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
expression = readline(prompt = "Enter the expression : ")
exp = eval(parse(text=expression))
```

- this is **potentially dangerous** (the user could enter, e.g., `system('del important_file.txt')`) (to be careful, you could check to make sure that the expression entered by the user didn't contain any suspicious characters - maybe it would only be allowed to have digits and math operators?)
- both `exp` and `expression` also refer to built-in functions in R; this code will work, but it's best practice to avoid names of existing functions

Comment: If the user inserts an invalid expression like a string then this coding will give an error right? I'm planning to use this code inside a loop so is there a method to print a warning message without terminating it in case an invalid input is entered?

Comment: see `?try`, `?tryCatch` ...